# Unicode in ggplot in Shiny

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a custom label using Unicode characters (and a color scale not shown here), specifically filled&unfilled, up&down triangles. Here's a working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:5)
ggplot(dd) + 
        geom_point(aes(x,y,shape = factor(y)), size = 10) +
        scale_shape_manual(values = c("\u25BC","\u25BD", "\u25A0", "\u25B3", "\u25B2"))
```

[image]

Now within Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(plotOutput("Basic")),
  function(input, output){
    dd <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:5)
    output$Basic <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(dd) + 
        geom_point(aes(x,y,shape = factor(y)), size = 10) +
        scale_shape_manual(values = c("\u25BC","\u25BD", "\u25A0", "\u25B3", "\u25B2"))})})
```

[image]

Finally, here is a screen of just the legend for a similar plot running on a local Linux shiny-server.
[image]
All five symbols are Unicode, as above, but only the hollow ones are improperly displayed.

Plotting directly in R, the characters show up fine on my machine. Plotting in shiny causes the unfilled triangles to show up as something else. There is no filled down triangle in pch, which is why Unicode even became necessary.

In the short run, I could use  `c(25, 6, 15, 2, 24)` with color and fill scales allocated just for these points, but that requires 3 different characteristics. I'd prefer to be able to just use any Unicode shape as ggplot allows.

EDITS: Added screenshots of the plots I see & Result from sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghsEt.png) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1re.png) LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghsEt.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghsEt.png) ggplot2_2.2.1 shiny_1.0.1   dplyr_0.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghsEt.png) Rcpp_0.12.8      digest_0.6.10    assertthat_0.1   mime_0.5         plyr_1.8.4       grid_3.3.3
 [7] R6_2.2.0         gtable_0.2.0     xtable_1.8-2     jsonlite_1.2     DBI_0.5-1        magrittr_1.5
[13] scales_0.4.1     lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3     Cairo_1.5-9      tools_3.3.3      munsell_0.4.3
[19] httpuv_1.3.3     rsconnect_0.7    colorspace_1.3-1 htmltools_0.3.5  tibble_1.2

Comment: I could not repro, they look identical on my Windows 10 laptop. Maybe you should put the contents of your `sessionInfo()` here. And a screen shot or two would help too.

Comment: I've added the `sessionInfo()` for my working machine, but I'm not sure how to get the equivalent for the shiny-server.